# iOS: How to stop receive keyboardWillShowNotification after keyboard keypress

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to do keyboard adaptive behaviour. I've subscribed on `keyboardWillShowNotification` and `keyboardWillHideNotification`, I receive all these events as expected. But I have a problem with `keyboardWillShowNotification`: I receive it once after pressing keyboard's button:

[image: Example]

Here is code of mine listener:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

// MARK: - View

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(text)
            Spacer()
            TextField("Input your text", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        .padding()
        .keyboardAdaptive()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

// MARK: - Keyboard hacks

extension Notification {
    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat {
        return (userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height ?? 0
    }
}

extension Publishers {
    static var keyboardHeight: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        let willShow = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification)
            .map { (n: Notification) -> CGFloat in
                print("will show")
                return n.keyboardHeight
            }

        let willHide = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification)
            .map { (n: Notification) -> CGFloat in
                print("will hide")
                return CGFloat(0)
            }

        return MergeMany(willShow, willHide)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

// MARK: -- Detect focused element
extension UIResponder {
    static var currentFirstResponder: UIResponder? {
        _currentFirstResponder = nil
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.findFirstResponder(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        return _currentFirstResponder
    }

    private static weak var _currentFirstResponder: UIResponder?

    @objc private func findFirstResponder(_ sender: Any) {
        UIResponder._currentFirstResponder = self
    }

    var globalFrame: CGRect? {
        guard let view = self as? UIView else { return nil }
        return view.superview?.convert(view.frame, to: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: -- Keyboard Adaptive Modifier

struct KeyboardAdaptive: ViewModifier {
    @State private var bottomPadding: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
                .padding(.bottom, self.bottomPadding)
                .onReceive(Publishers.keyboardHeight) { keyboardHeight in
                    let keyboardTop = geometry.frame(in: .global).height - keyboardHeight
                    let focusedTextInputBottom = UIResponder.currentFirstResponder?.globalFrame?.maxY ?? 0
                    self.bottomPadding = max(0, focusedTextInputBottom - keyboardTop - geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            }
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.16))
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func keyboardAdaptive() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: KeyboardAdaptive())
    }
}
```

I am a new guy in mobile development, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the code where you're using your keyboardHeight Publisher?

Comment: @Rob, thank you! I've updated the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples is to ignore same condition, like below. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct KeyboardAdaptive: ViewModifier {
    @State private var bottomPadding: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
                .padding(.bottom, self.bottomPadding)
                .onReceive(Publishers.keyboardHeight) { keyboardHeight in
                    // Just ignore equal resend
                    if keyboardHeight > 0 && self.bottomPadding > 0 { return }   // << here !!

                    let keyboardTop = geometry.frame(in: .global).height - keyboardHeight
                    let focusedTextInputBottom = UIResponder.currentFirstResponder?.globalFrame?.maxY ?? 0
                    self.bottomPadding = max(0, focusedTextInputBottom - keyboardTop - geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            }
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.16))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JSorel, no more than all what you do after *// MARK: - Keyboard hacks* ;) ... it is just a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only in the first `keyboardWillShowNotification` the `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and the `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` contain different CGRects values. In subsequent notifications both begin and end Rects are the same. You can use this as an indicator to just ignore the subsequent notifications.

On the other hand, I believe getting another `keyboardWillShowNotification` after pressing a key on an already presented keyboard, is a bug in iOS. It happens in UIKit as well, not just when using SwiftUI.